# Accessing Bug Reports and Termux storage in file explorer?

Tags: file-system, file-management, termux, bug-report-feature

A lot of apps call Android's "Open file" dialog when they want the user to select any file on their phone - for example when attaching a file to an email, or when opening a file with an editor. This dialog shows the phone's "Internal storage", attached USB storage and SD card, as well as extra locations such as cloud storage (Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox), **app-specific storage locations (e.g. Termux) and Android special locations like Bug Reports and System Traces.** The extra locations highlighted in yellow in this screenshot are the subject of this question:

[image: Extra locations in generic Open File dialog]

**Is there a file manager that can access these special locations like the file dialog?** Specifically, I want to access Bug Reports, but even seeing the Termux directory in any file browser is something I haven't been able to do.

My device is Samsung Galaxy S22+, so I tried Samsung's "My Files" app first, but I looked all over and there's no trace of these special directories:

[image: Samsung My Files]

Similarly, Files By Google doesn't show them anywhere:

[image: Files By Google]
[image: Files By Google side panel]

I also tried various other file managers, both from F-Droid and the Play Store, but absolutely none of them can access these folders.

Why can't file managers go here? How can I copy files off of there, other than by emailing them to myself or some other convoluted method (which also exposes sensitive data to other parties)?

Comment: See relevant Q&A here. [Android Documents Provider how to use and do I need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72859170/4720957)

Comment: They are not special directories but content providers backed by other apps which control what to show.

Comment: @Firelord thank you for that link. The "Files shortcut" app mentioned in the question works as a workaround for me!

Comment: @IrfanLatif, thanks for the clarification. I actually called them "special locations" (not directories) in most places as I didn't know what else to call them, I didn't think "Bug reports" and "System traces" were provided by an app and not just Android itself. OneDrive and GDrive are supported by every file manager under the sun, so as far as I could tell the only locations missing were actual directories somewhere in the filesystem.

Comment: I should also note that the reason I started looking for the Bug Reports provider in the first place is this post https://www.reddit.com/r/android_beta/comments/cq7fm1/where_is_the_bug_report_saved/

Comment: "*Similarly, Files By Google doesn't show them anywhere:*" apparently it's device-dependent, since Files By Google shows ["Other storage"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzc8Yl.png) on Pixel devices, including [Bug reports & System traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPVjll.png), but it's hidden on Samsung (and probably other) devices. On the other hand, I tried on Galaxy M21 and it's at least possible to access Bug reports & System traces from Developer options - System Tracing - View trace files. Despite selecting which app to open, it will be opened on a different file manager.